# Is there a way to produce executables from an existing Antlr4 grammar within expressions from the user?

Tags: c#, antlr4, grammar

I've already an existing application, in which I use Antlr4 in order to declare a customized grammar, compile the .g4 files into our c# base parser and lexer and also I've implemented the visitors for expression parsing.

The question is about finding a way to change the behavior from interpretation to compilation.

The way the app works today, we receive an expression from our users (in the customized grammar format), pass it through Antlr4 implementations in order to get our visitors running and executing the expression. This is a very repetitive process, considering the same expression gets evaluated over and over with just different arguments, the implemented logic is just the same.

I'd like to ask about if I could compile the provided expression of my users, save the compiled artifact so I can load it up and call it instead of parsing their expressions every time.
This is similar I do with C# programming, considering that I produce a DLL file that will get loaded up and executed later, without needing to get interpreted every time (not considering JIT at this context ;).

Hope I made my self clear enough about that.

It's not a problem to change architecture for this implementation, so we do need a "facelift" on the project, because of performance issues. Our customers use to produce very large expressions, which take lots of memory to be parsed and are causing some issues at runtime.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sure you can get intermediate representation of users code, but the problem is - how do you know expressions are the same? F.e., one extra space character in the expression will make it a "different" expression.

Comment: The purpose of this approach is to receive an expression from user, compile it and persist it for later usage. Then, if the user changes it, a new version of the expression is made, with a new compilation.
Each group of expressions represent an atomic unit of logic, so the user will produce it and then use it for many operations through the software usage.

Answer (score 0):

After some extra time analysing the implementation and also the usage we have of AntLr, I could see that even though I could find a way to compile expressions analysis, the output results wouldn't be executable for our scenario, because of many usages of local libraries.

The path I choose to run on was to create, dynamicaly, C# code while visiting AntLr expression navigation, through visit methods overrides and, later, compile this C# code into a memory assembly, so I can locate the execution class, create instance and invoke it's execute method. Also I'm using Rosyln to achieve this approach.